# Lipschitz condition in non-autonomous case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to show the RHS of

$\frac{dy}{dt}=-y^2+y+2yt^2+2t-t^2-t^4=f(t,y)$

is locally lipschitz.

Am I able to use continuously differentiable implies locally lipschitz here with non-autonomous $f$?

Is the RHS continuously differentiable? If so what am I differentiating with respect to?

Are $y$ and $t$ independent here?

Answer (score 1):

When verifying the assumptions of the uniqueness theorem, you are to consider the function $f(t,y)=-y^2+y+2yt^2+2t-t^2-t^4$ on its own, as a function of two independent variables $t,y$.

If the theorem is stated as on Wikipedia ([Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)) then you need:

1. continuity with respect to $t$
2. local Lipschitz property with respect to $y$

To state the latter precisely: for every point $(t_0,y_0)$ there is a neighborhood $U$ containing it, and a number $L$ such that 
$$
|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|\le L |y_1-y_2| \tag{1}
$$
everywhere in $U$.

The property $(1)$ follows (via the Mean value theorem) from the continuity of the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial y$. (Recall that continuous functions are locally bounded; $L$ can be an upper bound for $|\partial f/\partial y|$.)

Comment: I tried using the definition got nowhere and wondered if there was an easier method as in the autonomous case where you just have to show $f$ is continuously differentiable.